# Django: How do I pass request URLs through urls.py?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a django app with the following entries related to logging out in `urls.py`:

```
(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page':'/logout_page/'}),
(r'^logout_page/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template':'registration/logged_out.html'}),
```

I want to add a "Log back in" link in `logged_out.html`, which requires me to know the location (URL) from where the user originally logged out.

How do I reference that URL in the `logout` dispatcher entry, and how do I pass it to the `logout_page` entry?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly understand what you mean by "passing variables here" but you can pass variables to the views from urls like this
r'^(category/page/(?P[0-9]+)/$
page_number is passed as a variable to the url

But what I think you are looking for is to pass the previous prefer which you should be able access in the template like this :

{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}

So you can do something like :
  Login

in the template of logout_page to achieve what you are looking for